# Convert string into variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If in a class, I have a instance variable: nsstring *foo, now I want a create a variable with a string @"foo".

Example: I have the string @"foo", and with this string, I want a do: myobject.foo.

Comment: Not making much sense to me so far - do you want to create a NSString and retain it or something? What is method "do" supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is KVC [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html).

It enables you to retrieve or set a property or an instance variable on an object by it's name (a String). You can do something like:

```
id fooValue = [myobject valueForKey:@"foo"];
[myobject setValue:barValue forKey:@"foo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have setter and getter methods (or have synthesized them), you could use NSSelectorFromString() to access and modify your variable.

Accessing:

```
id foo = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"foo")];
```

Modifying:

```
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:, [@"foo" capitalizedString]]) withObject:foo];
```